# How can we get the calibration plot for Cox regression?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, biostatistics, epidemiology

The calibration plot for logistic regression is quite intuitive for me because we can directly get the predicted probability. However, in Cox regression model we just get the hazard ratio so how can we transform it into the probability?

Answer (score 1):

I cover this in some detail [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/cox#sec-cox-rel-val).  Use the smooth calibration method, not the stratified Kaplan-Meier method.  See various case studies in *Regression Modeling Strategies*.

Comment: Hello Prof. Harrell, thanks for your material. I check for the process and I am just wondering that how can we estimate the survival function（S_hat(t | x)） for each individual based on cox regression? Because cox regression just can estimate the hazard ratio.

Comment: @StevenXu after a Cox model is fit, you use the coefficient values to estimate the baseline cumulative hazard function $H_0(t)$; see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/46532/28500), for example. You then adjust the baseline cumulative hazard for covariates $x$ to get $H(t|x)$ and transform to a survival estimate via $S(t|x)=\exp(-H(t|x))$. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/206291/28500) outlines how the smooth calibration method works.

Comment: Survival probability estimates are easily computed using the R `survival` package `survfit` function or the R `rms` package `survest` and `Survival` functions.  The latter composes an R function to compute $S(t|X)$ from the linear predictor $X\beta$.